# wifi problem in 14.04

Tags: wireless

can anyone please help me - i'm not able to see any wifi enable option in ubuntu 14.04 and i'm not able find what the problem is ?
/*I don't think it depends on laptop any how mine is ASUS X550CC.*/
please help me.

Comment: Can you see the net indicator on top right near volume, battery etc?

Comment: Start with that question, then let us know if you can't figure something out. Also, what wireless card do you have? (`lspci -nn | grep Network`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the net indicator, right click on it and select "enable wifi"